# condition on several std::atomic<T>

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

In my multithreaded application I have a condition that can be reduced to this example

```
std::atomic<bool> a, b;
// ...
if ( a.load() && b.load() )
{
   // ...
}
```

Obviously, directly after the condition, a and b can hold different values.

In my application it holds that, if both values are true simultaneously, they cannot change state ever again. But after `a.load()` returned `true` it might change its value even before `b.load()` is evaluated.

Is there an *elegant* solution for atomically evaluating this statement? Obviously locking every call of a.store(..) and b.store(..) would work here, but that's far from nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered using an `atomic<int>` instead, and setting bits for the bools? This would allow you to query both atomically.

Comment: interesting approach, I like it! Now what if I have different thread-safe structures of completely different type?

Comment: There's no way in C++ to work with multiple `atomic<>`s atomically. Really there's no way in most CPUs. You're stuck with a mutex if you can't fit everything into 64 bits (or whatever your platform's maximum native atomic size is).

Comment: @stefan: What do your mean by "completeley different type? I think you are trying to generalize your question to the scenario where you need to atomically evaluate `if (cond1() && cond2()) { ... }`, with the condition that once `cond1()` and `cond2()` will *both* return `true` once, neither of them will ever return `false` again. But there's no other way of doing this atomically than locking both evaluations into a critical section

Comment: @AndyProwl I think I can rewrite my app to only use std::atomic<int>, but my original design involved different thread-safe calls to some custom classes.

Comment: @stefan: the generic solution is to bundle all conditions into a single structure.

Comment: @MatthieuM. True, but not exactly elegant

Comment: @stefan: when the solution is not elegant, it may be that the problem was ill-formulated. Could it be that there is a better design for what you are trying to achieve ? Locks & atomics are very low-level primitives.